# Assigning Values to DropDownList in Grid

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a DropDownList in a Grid and I have a foreach loop that loops through a Query and matches data and fills the drop down list for each row on that. But It is putting the data all in the same dropdownlist. So row 1, row 2, row 3, etc. all get combined into the dropdownlist. I am trying to make it so in row 1 dropdlownlist has the info for row 1 and row 2 the dropdownlist has the info for row 2 and so on.

I have this so far:

```
protected void grdExceptions_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
  {
    var linqContext = new DataClassesDataContext();
    var sessionleads = from q in linqContext.Leads where q.SessionID == SessionId orderby q.RowIndex select q;

    if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
      {
        foreach(var p in sessionleads)
          {
            var lQuery = (from a in gServiceContext.CreateQuery("account") where (a["name"].Equals(p.AccountName) &&
                                         a["address1_postalcode"].Equals(p.ZipCode) &&
                                         a["address1_stateorprovince"].Equals(p.State)) ||
                                        (a["address1_line1"].Equals(p.Address1) &&
                                         a["address1_postalcode"].Equals(p.ZipCode) &&
                                         a["address1_city"].Equals(p.City))
          select new
          {
            Name = !a.Contains("name") ? string.Empty : a["name"]
          });
          foreach (var a in lQuery)
            {
              ((e.Item as GridDataItem)["Account"].FindControl("AccountList") as DropDownList).Items.Add(new ListItem(a.Name.ToString()));
            }
          }
    }
  }
```

I have a DropDownlist in the ItemTemplate of the Grid. So for the first row I would want whatever matches are found assigned to the drop downlist in the first row, for the second row I would want whatever matches the dropdownlist in the second row, etc.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't appear to have any code that constrains the dropdown contents based on the current item, so your query results are going to be the same for each row in the grid.

Comment: How do you constrain it? That's what I can't figure out.

Comment: You need to start by asking yourself, what data is on each row that should limit the contents of the dropdown box. Once you have that information you should be able to extract that information from e.Item and add it to your query.

Comment: Actually it is constrained based on the p.Whatever. the p in sessionLeads is the data that is out into each row. It just seems to use one dropdown for all the data and not create a new one for each row.

Comment: Are you seeing lots of duplicate dropdownlists or just one overstuffed list somewhere in your grid?

Comment: There is a Dropdownlist for each row, which is the way I want it. It just crams all the same data intoo each dropdownlist. Instead of Row 1 matches Bob and Frank, so only put those in for row one and row 2 matches Joe and John so put those in for row 2. It puts all of them in each drop down list.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're expecting SessionId to somehow be different when ItemDataBound fires for each new row, but it's just staying the same. Do you have some other filter criteria you could add to your where clause? Or some way to update SessionId for each new row?